# Please let me know if there are any exceptions to this statement I figured out

Tags: c++

After some experimenting, I got to know something and I'd like to generalize it as follows:

> The member functions of an instance of a user defined class can not only access its own private data members, but also the private data members of other instances of the same class passed to them as arguments.

Please let me know if this holds true in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. This is called "sibling access." More generally, a private member function of a class can access private data members of *any* instance of the same class, provided that it has access to a variable of that type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, thank you for confirming. It's strange that I haven't seen it explicitly mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Please share if you know something extra along the same lines.

Comment: @Grendan It is mentioned in (a) the language specification #11 (in my copy, ISO/IEC 14882 1998), (b) *The Annotated C++ Reference Manual,* Ellis & Stroustrup, 1992,  #11, (c) *The Design and Evolution of C++,* Stroustrup 1994, #2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. Member access control in C++ is by class, not by instance. Member functions of a class can access the private and protected members of all instances of that class, as well as protected members of classes it inherits from. Also, if the class is named as a friend in some other class, it can access the private and protected members of any instances of that other class.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the extra info (about subclasses). :)